# regex in Java to match a string of words with spaces between

Tags: java, regex, variables

I cant be the first to ask this but I cant find it anywhere, so...

I want to match and capture a list of 'variable names' separated by spaces. The input is a string has nothing extraneous and is of the format

```
<var> <var> <var> ... <var>
```

where each variable < var > is a typical programming language-type variable: first a letter, then any number of (including none) letters and/or digits.

I'm using the regex string

```
"(?i)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[\\s+([a-z][a-z0-9]*)]+"
```

and I'm spelling out eg a-z to avoid use of messy backslashes.

The pattern basically works but when I get the Matcher's groupCount(), it is always = 1 and it's the whole input. Why are the variables not being captured?

My logic is to match the first variable, then to match repeating pairs of whitespace and another variable. Did I mis-state the repeating pattern? I do have an alternative, which is to use split() if the pattern is matched but I'd like to understand regex better. Also, strangely, the pattern matches ONE variable when no required space after it is present, when the variable's length is > 1, eg "abc" .. I dont understand how that happens.

Comment: Post the code you have. Did you use `while(matcher.find()) { /*get the matches here*/ }`?

Answer (score 0):

`[\\s+([a-z][a-z0-9]*)]` is a *character class* meaning: Match any of the following

- whitespace
- `(`
- a-z
- 0-9
- `*`
- `)`

You probably meant to use `(xx)` or `(?:xx)`, not `[xx]`.

With `(xx)` you'll get `groupCount() == 3`.
With `(?:xx)` you'll get `groupCount() == 2`.

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/vnFCVJ) for example, which also shows that none of it is what you want, since you only get the first and last variable.

You can use the regex to *validate* your string, but `split()` is the best way to then get the values you want.

Comment: thank you. I knew the square brackets didnt seem right but didn't think  parentheses would be right -- it explains the strange mismatch. I didn't think about catpuring or non-cap group types but I'll try them. The IDEONE example is clear. But since I haven't tried new code yet, I'm still unsure that groupCount will be right or if I'll need split(). It seems with all the regex corrections, the groups should already be captured, but then again, with past experience in mind, they may be in nested groups (php,ColdFusion) and getting them is hardly worth it compared to split().

Comment: p.s. - still havent coded it, but with groupCount only being 2 or 3 with the new expressions, I see it's probably not possible to have regex return all the pieces.. I thought it would be possible. but split will work too. thanks again.